# Why i am not able to run a php file from outside the current directory?

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to run this below php script from a directory outside the php file.

```
<?PHP
$pan = $argv[1];
$aa = 'java -cp :bcmail-jdk15-143.jar:bcprov-ext-jdk15-143.jar:com.sun.net.ssl.jar 
PanVerification '. $pan;
echo exec($aa);
```

All the required files are in the same directory where PHP file is.
If I run the PHP file from this current directory it works, but running the file from a different directory gives an error `Error: Could not find or load main class PanVerification Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PanVerification`.
I am stuck with this issue since last 2 days. I have tried most of the solutions available over the internet.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is some ways to do it, but the simplest way is using 'include' or 'required' php command:

```
include ('/somewhere/outside/of/your/htdocs/file.php');
```

Please note you may need to turn off 'open_basedir' php directive.

Comment: Which file are you asking to include? Its a java class which already there in the same folder.